# Why is the handling of exceptions from CloseHandle different between .NET 4 and 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, interop, pinvoke

I'm encountering a situation where a PInvoke call to `CloseHandle` is throwing an `SEHException` in a .NET 4 application when run under a debugger. Unlike [others who have encountered similar issues migrating from 3.5 to 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838957/getting-interopservices-sehexception-on-dllimport-routine-during-debug-after-mig), I'm not particularly bothered by the behaviour, and have already located the problem (a third party library calling `CloseHandle` twice on the same handle). However, I am perplexed as to why this behaviour doesn't happen in a .NET 3.5 application.

The following small but complete example demonstrates the behaviour I'm experiencing (tested on both XP SP3 and Win 7 x64, always compiled as x86):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(new IntPtr(-1), IntPtr.Zero, 0x04 /* read write */, 0, 0x1000, null);
            CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
            CloseHandle(hFileMapping);
            Console.WriteLine("No exception");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern IntPtr CreateFileMapping(IntPtr hFile, IntPtr lpAttributes, int flProtect, int dwMaximumSizeHigh, int dwMaximumSizeLow, string lpName);

    [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
}
```

When run as a .NET 4 application, an `SEHException` is thrown at the second `CloseHandle`. As per the [documentation for `CloseHandle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx), this is expected behaviour:

> If the application is running under a debugger, the function will
>   throw an exception if it receives either a handle value that is not
>   valid or a pseudo-handle value. This can happen if you close a handle
>   twice, or if you call CloseHandle on a handle returned by the
>   FindFirstFile function instead of calling the FindClose function.

However, when compiled as a .NET 3.5 application (or CLR 2.0), no exception is thrown at the second `CloseHandle` call, and the message `"No exception"` is printed.

According to [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx), the updated CLR released for .NET 4 has some different default behaviour with low-level exceptions that have potential to corrupt the process state. However, as far as I can understand from that article there is nothing mentioned of previous CLR behaviour that would cause the exception to be completely ignored.

**Why does a .NET 3.5 (or CLR 2.0) application not exhibit the documented behaviour of `CloseHandle` that is present in .NET 4?**

Comment: I for one am glad that MS made some improvements in this arena. I struggled with the issues here for ages: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/b5b7a179-3737-4380-b6cf-843f3e71b317/

Comment: Maybe in pre .NET 4 they were just silently catching and ignoring those exceptions

Comment: Which is precisely what I'm interested in finding out - why that might be the case :)

Comment: Is the actual third party library *identical* or perhaps dependent on the version of the .NET framework you work with?

Comment: The actual third party library is identical, but irrelevant. The example code uses no third party library, unless you consider the Windows API.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Windows only generates the SEH exception when it sees that a debugger is attached.  A **native** debugger.  There was a change in the .NET 4 managed debugger that now makes Windows see such a debugger.  I can't find any decent links that document the exact details of this new behavior, sorry.

Edit: I found a decent one.  Bullet 8 at the bottom of [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rmbyers/archive/2008/10/27/icordebug-re-architecture-in-clr-4-0.aspx):

> Under the hood we're built on the native debugging pipeline
>   In v2-compat mode, ICD continues to own the pipeline to the target process (since that was the V2 model), but that pipeline is no longer a collection of shared IPC objects with the target process, but is instead the same pipeline a native debugger uses.  Specifically, we attach to a process by calling kernel32!DebugActiveProcess, and get our managed events (things that result in calls to ICorDebugManagedCallback) using kernel32!WaitForDebugEvent.  **This also means that kernel32!IsDebuggerPresent now returns true when doing managed-only debugging.** This also has the nice side-effect of avoiding the problem with doing managed-only debugging when a kernel debugger is enabled (the OS assumes any breakpoint instructions that occur when a debugger isn't attached should cause a break in the kernel debugger).

This is not just a cosmetic fix btw, albeit that handle recycle attacks is something that keeps Microsoft employees awake at night.  The .NET 4 version of the CLR is built with the CRT version that checks for buffer overflows.  When one is detected, the CRT immediately terminates the program.  No AppDomain.UnhandledException, it is an immediate crash to the desktop.  This code however does the same thing that Windows does, check for a native debugger and generate a breakpoint when one is attached.  So it was pretty important that the managed debugger started looking like a native one, the only way to really diagnose the crash.

Comment: That would also explain why it suddenly does start breaking in .NET 3.5 when "Debug Native Code" is selected in the project properties (which I found out the other night when attempting to have a look into this again). Thanks!

Comment: Yup, turning on unmanaged debugging support in earlier versions makes the debugger call WaitForDebugEvent().

Answer (score 1):

No really 'good' answer to this.. 3.5 had a bug in the SEH that got fixed in 4.0.. It was eating the exception. I had a similar issue and we opened a ticket with MSFT on it -- their answer was 'bugfix'.

Comment: Did you open a Connect request? If so, can you post a link to it?

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Hans Passant also says there was a bug, which means there was a bug, linking to the ticket wouldn't prove anything.

Comment: We don't have Connect, just opened a one-off support ticket.. Looks like Hans provided details on what that fix was below as well..

Comment: @Ramhound: it wasn't a question of proof, but rather it would have provided a link to more information about the bug.